# Footer horizontal alignment within block / inline-block

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue where I just cannot get my footer to line up to a decent looking center aligned text, and center aligned content relative to the width of the sidebar.

Images of my issue are here (not aligned):

sidebar full width:
[image]

sidebar shrunk:
[image]

My current code is as follows:

CSS

```
#cl-wrapper .cl-footer {
    border-top: 1px solid #131519;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #2A2C31 inset;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #1F2126;
    color: #777;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

#cl-wrapper .cl-footer > .row {
    clear: both;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 19px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<footer class="cl-footer">
<div class="row">
    <?php echo (ENVIRONMENT === 'development') ? 'Page rendered in <strong>{elapsed_time}</strong> seconds. Using <strong>{memory_usage}</strong> of memory | ' . 'CodeIgniter Version <strong>' . CI_VERSION . '</strong><br />' : '' ?>Copyright &copy; <?=date('Y')?> | Eridian Pty Ltd | All Rights Reserved
</div>
</footer>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you post the rendered html (with the output after the PHP runs, instead of the php script) and include the sidebar html/css as well? (your CSS includes `#cl-wrapper` and your HTML doesn't  show that, so clearly there is more going on that is relevant to the issue :-) Ideally, it would be great if you can reproduce as a snippet or codepen (http://codepen.io)

Comment: There is no real difference, but its here below:
<footer class="cl-footer">
    <div class="row">
        Page rendered in <strong>0.0652</strong> seconds. Using <strong>1.64MB</strong> of memory | CodeIgniter Version <strong>3.0.3</strong><br>Copyright © 2016 | Eridian Pty Ltd | All Rights Reserved
    </div>
</footer>

I cannot replicate on a site like that unfortunately as there is alot of code making it all up. the controlling elements are above.

Comment: it looks like the whole footer is being pushed right (so it extends off the screen) so the text is actually still centered, you just can't see the whole container.  If you can post your full html, CSS, and any JS you are using to shrink/expand the sidebar, I'm happy to suggest a fix, but you haven't included enough information so far.

Comment: Thanks heaps for your comments, Turned out a mixture of changes were needed and something I missed to a JS id was throwing this out as well (for the menu collapse). I am adding the footer to something that was never designed to have one so has taken some work!

Comment: no problem - glad you found a solution that works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
display: table;
margin: 0 auto;
```

Hey. Maybe this will work. This is how it looks [on my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqd0c.png).

Comment: This worked in conjunction with another fix to and id (with specific JS styling) that I had omitted from the original code above, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use this code and attach it to the proper section's class, whatever they may be called. The width number and the margin number for the content and footer is most likely attached to a javascript that handles the toggle of the sidebar closing. Make sure they are the same.

```
#wrapper {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.page-sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 210px;  /* This number  */
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding-top: 50px;
    z-index: 2;
    background:#333;
}


.page-content {
    margin-left: 210px;  /* This number  */
    min-height: 100%;
    padding-top: 50px;
    background:#999;
}

footer {
    background:#eee;
    margin-left: 210px;  /* This number  */
    padding: 15px 20px;
    border-top: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
    height: 51px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align:center;
}
```

See the working [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/obyZbq)

Comment: It was to do with the JS toggle (an id I omitted from the above question), thank you very much